# What does the term "canonical form" or "canonical representation" in Java mean?

Tags: java

I have often heard this term being used, but I have never really understood it.

What does it mean, and can anyone give some examples/point me to some links?

EDIT: Thanks to everyone for the replies. Can you also tell me how the canonical representation is useful in equals() performance, as stated in Effective Java?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Wikipedia points to the term [Canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization).

> A process for converting data that has more than one possible representation into a "standard" canonical representation. This can be done to compare different representations for equivalence, to count the number of distinct data structures, to improve the efficiency of various algorithms by eliminating repeated calculations, or to make it possible to impose a meaningful sorting order.

The **Unicode** example made the most sense to me:

> Variable-length encodings in the Unicode standard, in particular UTF-8, have more than one possible encoding for most common characters. This makes string validation more complicated, since every possible encoding of each string character must be considered. A software implementation which does not consider all character encodings runs the risk of accepting strings considered invalid in the application design, which could cause bugs or allow attacks. The solution is to allow a single encoding for each character. Canonicalization is then the process of translating every string character to its single allowed encoding. An alternative is for software to determine whether a string is canonicalized, and then reject it if it is not. In this case, in a client/server context, the canonicalization would be the responsibility of the client.

In summary, a standard form of representation for data. From this form you can then convert to any representation you may need.

Answer (score 73):

I believe there are two related uses of canonical: forms and instances.

A **canonical form** means that values of a particular type of resource can be described or represented in multiple ways, and one of those ways is chosen as the favored canonical form. (That form is *canonized*, like books that made it into the bible, and the other forms are not.) A classic example of a canonical form is paths in a hierarchical file system, where a single file can be referenced in a number of ways:

```
myFile.txt                                   # in current working dir
../conf/myFile.txt                           # relative to the CWD
/apps/tomcat/conf/myFile.txt                 # absolute path using symbolic links
/u1/local/apps/tomcat-5.5.1/conf/myFile.txt  # absolute path with no symlinks
```

The classic definition of the canonical representation of that file would be the last path. With local or relative paths you cannot globally identify the resource without contextual information. With absolute paths you can identify the resource, but cannot tell if two paths refer to the same entity. With two or more paths converted to their canonical forms, you can do all the above, plus determine if two resources are the same or not, if that is important to your application (solve *the aliasing problem*).

Note that the canonical form of a resource is not a quality of that particular form itself; there can be multiple possible canonical forms for a given type like file paths (say, lexicographically first of all possible absolute paths). One form is just selected as the canonical form for a particular application reason, or maybe arbitrarily so that everyone speaks the same language.

Forcing objects into their **canonical instances** is the same basic idea, but instead of determining one "best" representation of a resource, it arbitrarily chooses one instance of a class of instances with the same "content" as the canonical reference, then converts all references to equivalent objects to use the one canonical instance.

This can be used as a technique for optimizing both time and space. If there are multiple instances of equivalent objects in an application, then by forcing them all to be resolved as the single canonical instance of a particular value, you can eliminate all but one of each value, saving space and possibly time since you can now compare those values with reference identity (==) as opposed to object equivalence (`equals()` method).

A classic example of optimizing performance with canonical instances is collapsing strings with the same content. Calling `String.intern()` on two strings with the same character sequence is guaranteed to return the same canonical String object for that text. If you pass all your strings through that canonicalizer, you know equivalent strings are actually identical object references, i.e., aliases

The enum types in Java 5.0+ force all instances of a particular enum value to use the same canonical instance within a VM, even if the value is serialized and deserialized. That is why you can use `if (day == Days.SUNDAY)` with impunity in java if `Days` is an enum type. Doing this for your own classes is certainly possible, but takes care. Read *Effective Java* by Josh Bloch for details and advice.

Answer (score 37):

A good example for understanding "canonical form/representation" is to look at the XML schema datatype definition of "boolean":

- the "lexical representation" of boolean can be one of: `{true, false, 1, 0}` whereas
- the "canonical representation" can only be one of `{true, false}`

This, in essence, means that

- `"true"` and `"1"` get mapped to the canonical repr. `"true"` and
- `"false"` and `"0"` get mapped to the canoncial repr. `"false"`

see [the w3 XML schema datatype definition for boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean)

Answer (score 32):

The word "canonical" is just a synonym for "standard" or "usual". It doesn`t have any Java-specific meaning.

Comment: canonical has a richer meaning than standard or usual IMO.

Answer (score 22):

reduced to the simplest and most significant form without losing generality

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to remember it is the way "canonical" is used in theological circles, canonical truth is the real truth so if two people find it they have found the same truth. Same with canonical instance. If you think you have found two of them (i.e. `a.equals(b)`) you really only have one (i.e. `a == b`). So equality implies identity in the case of canonical object.

Now for the comparison. You now have the choice of using `a==b` **or** `a.equals(b)`, since they will produce the same answer in the case of canonical instance but a==b is comparison of the reference (the JVM can compare two numbers extremely rapidly as they are just two 32 bit patterns compared to `a.equals(b)` which is a method call and involves more overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Another good example might be: you have a class that supports the use of cartesian (x, y, z), spherical (r, theta, phi) and cylindrical coordinates (r, phi, z). For purposes of establishing equality (equals method), you would probably want to convert all representations to one "canonical" representation of your choosing, e.g. spherical coordinates. (Or maybe you would want to do this in general - i.e. use one internal representation.) I am not an expert, but this did occur to me as maybe a good concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

A canonical form means a naturally unique representation of the element

Answer (score 0):

canonical representation means view the character in different style
for example if I write a letter A means another person may write the letter A in different style:)

This is according to OPTICAL CHARACTER RECOGNITION FIELD

Answer (score 0):

The OP's questions about *canonical form* and how it can improve performance of the `equals` method can both be answered by extending the example provided in Effective Java.

Consider the following class:

```
public final class CaseInsensitiveString {

  private final String s;

  public CaseInsensitiveString(String s) {
    this.s = Objects.requireNonNull(s);
  }

  @Override 
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString && ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s.equalsIgnoreCase(s);
  }
}
```

The `equals` method in this example has added cost by using `String`'s `equalsIgnoreCase` method.  As mentioned in the text

> you may want to store a canonical form of the field so the equals
>   method can do a cheap exact comparison on canonical forms rather than
>   a more costly nonstandard comparison.

What does Joshua Bloch mean when he says *canonical form*?  Well, I think Dónal's concise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280119/2860319) is very appropriate. We can store the underlying `String` field in the `CaseInsensitiveString` example in a *standard* way, perhaps the uppercase form of the `String`. Now, you can reference this *canonical form* of the `CaseInsensitiveString`, its uppercase variant, and perform cheap evaluations in your `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical Data in RDBMS, Graph Data;
Think as "Normalization" or "Normal form" of a data in a RDBMS. Same data exists in different tables, represented with a unique identifier and mapped it in different tables.
or
Think a single form of a data in Graph Database that represented in many triples.

Major benefit of it is to make Dml (Data manipulation) more efficient since you can upsert (insert/update) only one value instead of many.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, when defining reusable types for functions, it's common to have two related types: a canonical form for return types and a looser form for parameters. Here's what these terms typically mean:

Canonical Form (Return Type): The canonical form, in the context of return types, represents the strictest and most specific type that describes what a function returns. It's often used to define the precise shape of the data that a function is expected to return. This form aims to capture the exact structure and type of the returned value as accurately as possible.

Looser Form (Parameters): The looser form, typically applied to parameters, is a type that is more permissive or general. It allows for various input values, which may include a wider range of possibilities. This form is less specific than the canonical form and is designed to accept different input values and types.

This approach provides flexibility in your code. By having a canonical form for return types, you can ensure that functions produce specific types of results, which is especially useful for type checking and understanding what functions return. On the other hand, using a looser form for parameters allows functions to accept a broader range of input values, making them more versatile.

Here's a simple example:

```
// Canonical form for return type
function multiply(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a * b;
}

// Looser form for parameters
function add(a: number | string, b: number | string): number | string {
  return a + b;
}
```

In this example, the multiply function has a canonical form that specifies it returns a number. The add function has a looser form for parameters, allowing it to accept both numbers and strings as inputs and returning a type that can be either a number or a string.

Using these canonical and looser forms in your type definitions can help you strike a balance between type safety and flexibility in your code.

Comment: the question is (only) marked with the [tag:java] tag... (and 15 years old [in 9 days])